# Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I keep getting this error message when compiling my app to an apk:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvHVI.png) I've found a lot of posts about `pom.xml`
I tried multiple times to find the `pom.xml` file. So does anyone know where it is or how to fix this error?

This is my android studio version btw: [version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWGVH.png)

Comment: There is no `pom.xml` file for android apps

Comment: Yea, sorry, I was in a rush. I edited the post. It has a little more detail now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest Android Studio does not support java 1.5 as a compilation target. Switch to 1.6 or later (newest recommendation is java 11). Here is how:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    // For Kotlin projects
    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

[source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=nl#java-11)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jakos, I found the following in my app\build.gradle :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
}
```

This was probably left over from upgrading an eclipse project, once removed the project compiled.

Comment: Dont forget to check also dependent libraries. In my case it was one of those.